# Python. Finding the Quadratics Equation given Its Roots

Tags: python-3.x

Kindly help me write a simple python program that takes the two roots of a quadratics equation as  functions and returns the complete quadratics equation..Sort of reversing the quadratics equation

Comment: How is the quadratic equation given?
Do you know the Quadratic formula?

Comment: you are for instance given two roots x1=1.5 and x2= 1.6 and required to find the quadratic equation in the format  ax2+bx+c =0

Answer (score 1):

So, you're given two roots, let's call them a and b.

The math is as follows:

```
y = (x - a)(x - b)
y = x^2 - (a + b)x + ab
```

(Note that the right side of the equation can be multiplied by an arbitrary number.  There is no way to determine what that number is with the given information.)

Try implementing that and come back here with any questions related to your own code.